# Convert CocosBuilder CCB to PNG

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

I have a bunch of CCB files that consist of CCSprite and 4-5 layers - no animations.

I need a way to convert these CCBs to flat PNG images.

Creating Smart Sprite Sheets is not good, as it saves each layer as different sprite on the sheet and I need those merged. How would I do this?

Comment: Take a screenshot? Ccb and png are different formats, ccb is a proprietary document and png is an image.

Comment: figured maybe there's a converter that would merge all layers and export.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this....but if you really want a png file of a ccb file, why don't you take a screenshot of your file's layout in spritebuilder/cocosbuilder and save it as a png?

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with everyone that this sounds like a strange request. But, if you really need to save the result of loading CCB into PNG image you can try to use [`CCRenderTexture`](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCRenderTexture.html).